# Data type mismatch when creating pipe

Tags: type-mismatch, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a snowpipe which will load data from a S3 bucket into a table. My table contains a column of data type GEOGRAPHY.

When I am creating the snowpipe I get the following error message: "**SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting GEOGRAPHY but got VARCHAR(16777216) for column GEO_LOCATION**"

Why does it assume that the incoming column is of type **VARCHAR(16777216)**? How do I change this assumptiom? Because I know that my input column will be in the correct format.

Comment: Please update your question withe the create statement that is generating this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As for now**, snowpipe requires transformation when loading geo data. Here is the repro of the issue:

```
create or replace stage mystage;
create or replace table test ( a geography );
insert into test values ('POINT(-122.35 37.55)' );
copy into @mystage from test;
truncate table test;

copy into test from @mystage; -- works
truncate table test;

create or replace pipe test_pipe as -- fails with expecting GEOGRAPHY but got VARCHAR(16777216) for column A
copy into test from @mystage;
```

If you apply transformation, it should work:

```
create or replace pipe test_pipe as -- works
copy into test from (select to_GEOGRAPHY($1) from @mystage);

alter pipe test_pipe refresh;

select * from test;
```

This is a known issue, and it will be fixed in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your snowpipe definition:

TO_GEOGRAPHY( <varchar_expression> )